# Setting column equal to value depending on another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql

I am stuck on how to set the value of solvent column in each row to a number in the num column in the data frame. eg I need num to be equal to 9 when solvent is Nonane and num equal to 8 when solvent is Octane etc. Any help would be great.

[image]

Comment: Also typically you should post text rather than images as it allows others to copy-paste your input data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `.loc` with a boolean mask

```
df.loc[df['solvent'] == 'NONANE', 'num'] = 9
df.loc[df['solvent'] == 'OCTANE', 'num'] = 8
```

Another method is do define a dict and call `map`:

```
d = {'NONANE':9, 'OCTANE':8, 'HEPTANE':7, 'HEXANE':6}
df['num'] = df['solvent'].map(d)
```